# Convert C# Matrix to c++ FLOAT*

Tags: c#, c++, matrix, pinvoke

I need to get a SlimMath matrix from C# into managed c++ as a FLOAT* as cleanly as possible. So far all my attempts have been dirty and broken. Code looks something like this:

C#

```
Matrix m = Matrix.Identity;
//.......(transform matrix)
//.......Convert it to something I can get into c++ ??
myManagedCPPFunction(m.ToArray());
```

c++

```
void myClass::myManagedCPPFunction(?? matTransform)
{
    //FLOAT* f = reinterpret_cast<FLOAT*>(&matTransform); //Cant do this cause managed code
    otherClass->Go((FLOAT*)matTransform);
}

//This is existing code I'm trying to get to:
class otherClass
{
public:
virtual void STDMETHODCALLTYPE Go(const FLOAT *pTransformMatrix);
}
```

I hope that makes enough sense to work with.

Thanks!

Edit, I forgot to mention that this is working already for strings and regular floats, it's just the float[] -> float* thing I can't seem to get working.

I have been able to get it working this way, but it's not ideal:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (float* f = m.ToArray())
        myManagedCPPFunction(f);
}
```

Would prefer not to do that for obvious reasons.

OK I think I have it working now (at least it compiles and runs but now I need to play with the transformations) as follows:

```
void myClass::myManagedCPPFunction(SlimDX::Matrix^ matTransform)
{
     FLOAT* f = reinterpret_cast<FLOAT*>(&matTransform);
     otherClass->Go(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's managed C++ you can use the same types as in C#. Why not just declare the C++ method like this:

```
void myClass::myManagedCPPFunction(Matrix^ matTransform)
```

Comment: Yes, OK. I couldn't get it working before like that then I realized I would have to use SlimDX::Matrix^ and it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do declare it in C++ to be usable by C# (see [p/invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) tutorials):

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec( dllexport ) void STDMETHODCALLTYPE Go(float* pMatrix);

    void Go(float* pMatrix) {
       // do your stuff here. assume the matrix has 16 elements
    }
}
```

and in C#:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll")]
public static extern void Go(float[] matrix);
```

Sample C# code:

```
Matrix m = myMatrix;
Go(m.ToArray());
```

EDIT: if you use a C++/CLI managed assembly, then you could declare the function like this:

```
using namespace System;

public ref class Class1
{
    public:

        void Go(array<float> ^ pFloat)
        {
            ... 
        }
    };
```

Comment: The c++ side compiles fine but C# says:
cannot convert from 'float[]' to 'float*'. I am not using DLLImport, just have the c++ project inside my C# solution and a reference there.

Comment: How can you have this work without DllImport? are you doing COM?

Comment: I just have a c++ project in my C# solution, then I add a reference in the C# project which links the two. At that point I'm able to call functions in the c++ wrapper class directly from C#, I believe it makes use of System::Runtime::InteropServices.  It all works great with the exception of the transform matrix piece.

Comment: Please make this kind of "small detail" clear in the question. I made some edit.

Comment: I appreciate all your advice. this "small detail" was mentioned several times throughout my question and I even named my function myManagedCPPFunction.